# Adding lit-element and lit-html to a global variabel

Tags: rollup, lit-element, lit-html

I have several lit-elements on my page, but I can't compile them all together so I would like to "share" the lit stuff through a global variable. Might be a bit unconventional, but right now it will save me a lot of bytes.

I'm using rollup to do the packaging.

I think I'm pretty close to achieve what I want, but there is something that I'm missing...

This is my component..

```js
@customElement('tab-strip')
export class TabStrip extends LitElement {
```

Resulting in

```js
var tabstrip = (function (exports, litElement, repeat, classMap) { 
//SOME OTHER STUFF

  exports.TabStrip = class TabStrip extends litElement.LitElement {...
.
.
.
${repeat.repeat(this._tabs, e => litElement.html
  

}({}, Globals, Globals.repeat, Globals.classMap))
```

I have create a Globals.ts file that looks like this..

```js
import { customElement, html, LitElement, property } from "lit-element";
import { Template, TemplateResult } from "lit-html";
import { classMap } from "lit-html/directives/class-map";
import { repeat } from "lit-html/directives/repeat";

class Globals {
    public html = html;
    public LitElement = LitElement;
    public customElement = customElement;
    public property = property;
    public repeat = repeat;
    public classMap = classMap;
    public Template = Template;
    public TemplateResult = TemplateResult;

}
window["Globals"] = new Globals();
```

And at last my rollup.config

```js
input: inputDir + name + ".ts",
output: {
    file: outputDir + name + ".js",
    name: name,
    format: format,
    sourcemap: true,
    globals: {
        "lit-element": "Globals",
        'customElement': 'Globals.customElement',
        'lit-html': "Globals.LitHtml",
        'html': "Globals.html",
        'property': "Globals.property",
        'lit-html/directives/repeat': "Globals.repeat",
        'lit-html/directives/class-map': 'Globals.classMap',
        'Template': 'Globals.Template',
        'TemplateResult': 'Globals.TemplateResult'
    }
},
plugins: [
    typescript({
        experimentalDecorators: true
    }),
    resolve(),
    // terser({"ecma":"2019"}),
],
external: ['lit-element', 'lit-html', "lit-html/directives/repeat", "lit-html/directives/class-map"]
```

Gut feeling is that I have misunderstood something in the external stuff of rollup..
AS you can see in the generated file it says `litElement.LitElement` instead of just `litElement`

Any help??

Answer (score 0):

Does it work for you? This seems correct just taking it at face value.

Looking at what your `Globals` is, it's an object with the properties `LitElement`, `property`, `html`, and so on.

If we look at your tabstrip function, the second argument is `litElement`, which matches the `Globals` Object being passed in.

So `class TabStrip extends litElement.LitElement`

makes sense, since the `litElement` is referencing your `Globals` object, and that has the `LitElement` property.